# Why maximum recursion depth exceeded is not (always) happening in python list comprehension?

Tags: python, recursion, list-comprehension, depth

I noticed that "maximum recursion depth exceeded" does not happen when a basic recursive function is used inside a list-comprehension, while it does when used outside of it. I would like to understand why, to get a better understanding of how list-comprehension works and then use it efficiently.

I tried it with a basic fibonacci function applied on a range.

```py
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize = 2048)
def fib(n): return n if n<2 else fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)

# The following will be calculated (and 5000 can be replaced by much bigger integer)
fb = [fib(n)for n in range(5000)]
print(fb[-1])

# but next line:
print(fib(500))
# will cause a RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
# And will need this to be enabled:

import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(1024)
print(fib(500))
```

Answer (score 4):

Every time the comprehension evaluates `fib(n)`, it saves that result in the cache. By the time it gets to `fib(500)`, `fib(499)` and `fib(498)` are already cached, so they don’t run again. The stack goes 1 call of `fib` deep.

When you run `fib(500)` immediately, the first thing it evaluates is `fib(499)`, which isn’t cached and evaluates `fib(498)`, which isn’t cached and evaluates `fib(497)`… all the way down to `fib(1)`. The stack goes 499 calls of `fib` deep.

You should be able to see the same thing by running:

```
print(fib(250))
print(fib(500))
```

Comment: Oh, sure ! Nothing to do with list-comprehension, thank you. It of course will behave the same in a for loop.